# Rejected from iOS App Store for dyld_stub_binding_helper... what calls this?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Our iPad app has been rejected from the app store for private/restricted calls-to/use-of `dyld_stub_binding_helper`. The most explicit info I can find on this function is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html).

Our code does not directly reference this, and other than playing 20 questions with Apple, we do not know how to proceed. Has anybody encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just faced a problem exactly as you describe. (Rejection due to `dyld_stub_binding_helper`)

In our case, what happened was a .m file had someone wound up in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of our xcode project.  This led to the compiled bundle having a .o file included in it, which I think is what triggered the rejection.  Simply removing the .m from the build phase and re-uploading seems to have fixed it.

Comment: That fixed it. I can only upvote you once, but I pressed that mouse button *really* hard. Seriously, I kiss you! Thanks. How the hell did you find that?

Comment: On a hunch, we grepped for that string in the bundle we submitted to apple, and found it in the .o file.  (I had previously dealt with a ".o included in the compiled bundle" problem before, so I knew just how to fix that)

Answer (score 17):

In our case building with Xcode 5.0 Beta and iOS 7 results in

`symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Problem: Deployment Target was 3.0. Changing it to 4.3 fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the deployment target from 3.0 to higher (iOS 7.0) for example will help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it could relate to weak linking a library (which is not just valid, but suggested for providing multi-release support).  What libraries do you link?  How do you link them?

---

**Edit**:
go to where your .o files are built:

```
fs5h:armv7 bshirley$ pwd
/Users/bshirley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chuck-cmwxmjfrimatygfvsnqmcieylbaw/Build/Intermediates/Chuck.build/Debug-iphoneos/PointWorks.build/Objects-normal/armv7
fs5h:armv7 bshirley$ find . -name '*.o' -print -exec  nm '{}' \; -print | grep RectZero
    U _CGRectZero
```

in this example, i apparently have one file that uses `CGRectZero`,
my find/grep/exec foo has grown weak, i couldn't manage the pipe internal to the find command

this will confirm you're linking to the symbol they say,
then remove the end part, get a boatload of output and search for the culprit

Comment: I like your theory, but we don't weak-link anything.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out. We were looking at and ready to try almost anything, since we had no guidance from Apple, so far.

Comment: One suggestion I would have: rebuild the project from scratch.  Get a fresh install of Lion/Xcode 4.1.  Project->New.  Drop your files into the project add them all, get it going again.  Resubmit that.

Comment: `for i in *.o; do echo $i; nm $i | grep 'symbol'; echo '====================='; done`